# Select substring between last set of chars from last

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I'm needing to extract the substring between 2 chars (  "[" and "]"   ) but only for the last iteration.

here examples:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Text                                                                                ║ Expected result   ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ :OR1[253427815][11 Sep 2020][000685f383][Craft Labor ST][Standard]                  ║ Standard          ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ :OR1[252348249][11 Sep 2020][0006ff85383][Craft Labor-Allowance][Skill Rate 7]      ║ Skill Rate 7      ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ :OR1[2545528250][11 Sep 2020][00068ff5383][Craft Labor-Allowance][Attendance]       ║ Attendance        ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ :OR1[2528454248][11 Sep 2020][000685383][Craft Labor-Allowance][Overtime]           ║ Overtime          ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ :OR1[25254548247][11 Sep 2020][000685383][Craft Labor-Allowance][Weather Allowance] ║ Weather Allowance ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

I've tried with a combination of substring and charindex:

```
SELECT text, SUBSTRING( text, CHARINDEX( '][', text) + 2, 11 ) AS Expected_result
```

but I think I should do it to search for the right and only get everything but the last "]"  after finding the "][" combination

does this make sense? select form the right until finding the first ][  and then getting everything but the last ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT([text], CHARINDEX('[]', REVERSE([text]))-1), ']', '') AS Expected_result
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b9ce/1)

Answer (score 2):

One method is:

```
select replace(s.value, ']', '')
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.text, '[') s
where t.text like concat('%$[', s.value) escape '$';
```

An alternative in earlier versions:

```
select t.*, replace(replace(v.str, '[', ''), ']', '')
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.text, 1, len(t.text) - charindex('[', reverse(t.text)), ''))) v(str);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7282eb2f58bde73788f51a459d323daa) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I get an error on the string_split  I have sql-server 2014, and do you maybe know a way to do it without the cross apply? only in the select?

Comment: @Baldie47, it is possible. Please, see my answer. `STRING_SPLIT` has been provided in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon  although this didn't work for me, I'm sure it's my fault, as your responses are usually right :)  thank you!

Comment: @Baldie47 . . . There is a db<>fiddle illustrating that both work.